# How to do ongoing synchronization with Salesforce?

Tags: data-synchronization

I'd like to develop an app on Salesforce that updates an Activity record with the amount of time a lead spent viewing something like an email message. I would keep updating this record until the lead stops viewing the message. (Let's assume that I have a reliable way of determining that.)

From what I understand, I can keep pushing the updated viewing time to Salesforce, but a Salesforce user wouldn't know that it's been updated until he refreshes the page.

It seems to me that Salesforce's interface isn't set up for this kind of ongoing data manipulation. How could I make sure that the "viewed duration" metric is always accurate to a Salesforce user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach , However its not very reliable.

1. Use Inline Vissualforce page in Activity with hight 1px (So that would not be visible to user).
2. Start Javascript timer when Page loads.
3. In "onbeforeunload" event of page when user tries to navigate away from page, you can post AJAX request or REST request to update duration.